# How to design the class & it's method

Tags: java, architecture

Multiple clients send request to write a file and expecting a response either success or fail. I would like to describe concisly the work done at server side.

1. handle the request by servlet class and invoke another class to proceed the further.
2. `FileWriter` class is invoked and this class performs follwing the file writing process.
   ***a).*** create directory under context and write a `*.txt` file inside directory
   ***b).*** copy some files from context's existing directory to newly created directory.
   ***c).*** compress `(*.zip)` this directory

   `class FileWriter {`

   ```
   public synchronized writeFile(String contextPath) {
         creates a directory & new file under context

         copyFiles(path_to_directory);
   }

   private void copyFiles(String path_to_directory){
      copies files to /contextPath/directory/... from existingDirectory;  

    compressDir( Directory_path ); // to compress the file
    }

   private void compressDir(String Directory_path) {
          compress the newly created directory
    }
   ```

   `}`

As you can see above in the class that there is one method is `synchronized` and two methods are `private`. only `synchrnized` method is invoking from `servlet class` others method are invoking inside from the method. 
so is this a good / standard way to handling the multiple client request ?

or should i invoke each method directly from `servlet class`. please correct me and suggest a better way to implement the class.

***@Edit :*** `req1` comes and create directory & file e.g.
     `context/directory_1/file_1.txt`

in the mean time `req2` comes and checks that `directory_1` is existing already so it creates `directory_2` e.g.  `context/directory_2/file_1.txt`.

**now the second step** is to copy the file from context to newly created directory. Let me tell you `directory_1` has nothing to do with `directory_2`
 all the newly created directory copies the file from a common_directory e.g. `context/common_directory/...  to  context/directory_1,  context/directory_2'

*and third step* is to compress the directory : e.g. `directory_1.zip, directory_2.zip`

Comment: can two requests mutually exclusive or one has to wait for other's actions to finish, in your case creating dir etc..?

Comment: yes,you are right. one has to wait for other's actions of creating the directory

Comment: let me take an example. `req1` comes in n working on `dir1/files1` and in the mean time `req2` comes in, now does `req2` needs `req1` output or depends on `dir1/files1`

Comment: _synchronized method_ `req1` comes and create a directory inside context e.g. `context/file1` and in the mean time `req2`comes, it also create a directory under `context` but it got `files1` is existing already so it creates files2 e.g. `context\files2`. i mean to say creating directory name should be unique for each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the above code, if you calling `writeFile` from the servlet, your servlet ends up as a single threaded application.

If two are working on two separate directories and separate files and you guaranty that there is no overlap, you should call both methods directly and ditch `synchronized`. Looks like this is what your situation is. So you can use below approach:

```
Servlet Code

{
  ....
  String uniqDir = createUniqDir();
  copyFiles(uniqDir);
  compressDir(uniqDir);
}
```

Now the whole idea is to create uniq dir name. Now there are many approaches to create uniq dir name. I ll use one which is based on time-stamp.

```
String createUniqDir() {
   // Use SimpleDateFormat or just millis from Date 
   // We just trying to be as uniq as possible.
  String timeStampStr;
  Date now = new Date();
  timeStampStr = "" + now.getTime(); // If using EPOC
  // This soln if you wana use SimpleDateFormat
  // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS");
  // timeStampStr = sdf.format(dt);
  int counter = 1;

  String dirToCreateStr = "some_prefix-" + timeStampStr;
  File dirToCreate = new File(dirToCreate);

  while(!dirToCreate.mkdir()) {
    dirToCreateStr = "some_prefix-" + timeStampStr + "-" + counter;
    file = new File(dirToCreate);
    counter++;
  }
  return dirToCreateStr;
}
```

Since we are using `mkdir` and it is atomic and only return `true` if it is able to create a uniq dir. This soln is optimized as requesting colliding during a millisecond are way less and we dont need any synchronization overhead.

You can use some `counter` too for creating uniq name. But if your counter always starts from the beginning (i.e. you are not maintaining its state that too in a thread safe fashion) then you have performance/accuracy issues.

Comment: you mean make synchronised to `non-synchronise`and call other two methods directly from servlet?

Comment: havexz, please check the example. as i have edited my question

Comment: exactly, you got my point. the main goal is to create the unique folder and you gave me a nice solution but still we have `0.0001%` chance of duplicacy while i think it's better than `synchronization`. Thanks for your time & suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Two advices:

1. Do not name the class same to already existing class in JDK.
2. Do not chain method calls this way, create one-purpose methods and then
   put them together in one method clearly showing your intension.

   class FileProcessor /*FileUtil whatever, but not FileWriter */ {

   public synchronized writeFile(String contextPath) {
     // create a directory & new file under context

   copyFiles(contextPath);
     compressDir(contextPath); // to compress the file
   }

   // copies files to /contextPath/directory/... from existingDirectory;
   private void copyFiles(String path_to_directory){  }

   //  compress the newly created directory
   private void compressDir(String Directory_path) {  }

Comment: Thanks binary_runner, sure i''ll care about the class duplicay and also i was thinking about the chain method call. thanks for the pointing that out.